# Is there a way to create a mat-icon inside a mat-chip without the icons inner HTML leaking into the value of the chip?

Tags: angular, dom, angular-material

I am currently working on a directive that extends the default mat-chip element in Angular. As directives don't have a template, I need to use Renderer2 to create and manipulate elements in and around the chip.

My app uses Material v14 where mat-icon don't have a leadingIcon property. My solution is this block of code, that creates a MatIcon element programmatically and places it inside the mat-chip as a child element:

```
// Insert check mark if set to true
if (this.showCheckMark) {
    this.checkMarkContainerDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.checkMarkMatIcon = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(MatIcon);
    const check = this.renderer.createText('check');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.checkMarkMatIcon.instance._elementRef.nativeElement, check);
    this.renderer.addClass(this.checkMarkContainerDiv, 'transition-wrapper');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.checkMarkContainerDiv, this.checkMarkMatIcon.instance._elementRef.nativeElement);
    // inserts the checkMarkContainerDiv before first child of the mat-chip so that it appears before the text
    this.renderer.insertBefore(this.matChipElement, this.checkMarkContainerDiv, this.matChipElement.firstChild);
    }
```

The elements is created as expected and I can see the mat-icon element in the DOM. The problem is that the inner HTML, that I use to tell the mat-icon which icon to display, is leaking into the value of the chip when it is clicked inside a mat-chip-list:

[The 'change' event of the mat-chip-list returns the values of every selected chip. This value contains the name of the mat-icon that is a child of the chip.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDSDp.png)

There is another way of telling the mat-icon which icon to display and that is the "fontIcon" property. I have tried this before but it wouldn't display the correct icon. Instead it just renders as an empty mat-icon element. Does this maybe have to do with my timing? The icon is created within the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. Putting the name of the icon inside the inner HTML works fine though when done within the same hook.

Of course I have some code to strip away the leading "check " from my chips values but I would very much prefer a solution where this isn't necessary in the first place.

Thank you very much for reading this. I'm looking forward to hear your ideas!